# Could running two 15 amp circuits of NM wire in parallel cause interference?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm running some NM romex wire through conduit in a couple 20 ft. runs, two different 15 amp circuits - one for lights, one for outlets. Could running them parallel to each other in the same conduit cause interference or is this fine?

Comment: I thought that running NM in conduit was to be avoided because it prevents heat flow away from the wires.  I doubt that running two NM cables through the same conduit would cause electrical interference with ordinary devices, but could possibly cause induced voltages that would be troublesome for some sensitive devices.

Comment: This is a conduit sleeve for physical damage protection, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interference usually happens with cheap electronic dimmers and fan controls are on the same circuit, with the light flickering when the fan control is activated.  Other than that, nothing much I know of in my 20+ years of electrical.